# How to use the save appointment task for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to use the save appointment task for Windows Phone 8.1.
I am having option to save appointment task for Windows Phone 8 as below

```
SaveAppointmentTask saveAppointmentTask = new SaveAppointmentTask();
           saveAppointmentTask.StartTime = timeconversion.AddMinutes(-10);
           saveAppointmentTask.Location = sharingProgramTime; // appointment location
           saveAppointmentTask.Subject = sharingProgramName; // appointment subject
           saveAppointmentTask.Details = sharingProgramName  + sharingProgramTime; // appointment details
           saveAppointmentTask.IsAllDayEvent = false;
           saveAppointmentTask.Reminder = Reminder.TenMinutes;
           saveAppointmentTask.AppointmentStatus = Microsoft.Phone.UserData.AppointmentStatus.Busy;
           saveAppointmentTask.Show();
```

Like above, how to achieve the save appointment task in Windows Phone 8.1. Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: What's not working about that code?

Comment: SaveAppointmentTask it applies for Windows Phone 8 only.It has removed in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Are you using the WinRT or Silverlight APIs?

Comment: And [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.saveappointmenttask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) clearly states that it is supported in 8.0 and 8.1

Comment: Please Refer this https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-Store-81-vs-25c80c2a in this it stresses that **"namespace "Microsoft.Phone.Tasks" is no longer available in store 8.1 OS."** in the Descrition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've moved from Silverlight to Windows Runtime, you need to change to use the [`AppointmentManager` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.appointments.appointmentmanager.aspx)

There is [a sample in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/managing-appointments), but your code would be roughly equivalent to:

```
private async void Add-Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create an Appointment that should be added the user's appointments provider app.
    var appointment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.Appointment();

    appointment.StartTime = timeconversion.AddMinutes(-10);
    appointment.Location = sharingProgramTime; // appointment location
    appointment.Subject = sharingProgramName; // appointment subject
    appointment.Details = sharingProgramName  + sharingProgramTime; // appointment details
    appointment.IsAllDayEvent = false;
    appointment.Reminder = new TimeSpan(0,10,0); // Ten minutes
    appointment.BusyStatus = AppointmentBusyStatus.Busy;

    // Get the selection rect of the button pressed to add this appointment
    var rect = GetElementRect(sender as FrameworkElement);

    // ShowAddAppointmentAsync returns an appointment id if the appointment given was added to the user's calendar.
    // This value should be stored in app data and roamed so that the appointment can be replaced or removed in the future.
    // An empty string return value indicates that the user canceled the operation before the appointment was added.
    String appointmentId = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Appointments.AppointmentManager.ShowAddAppointmentAsync(
                           appointment, rect, Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Default);
}
```

Comment: Hi Rowland Shaw Thank you for the response. I can get the outlook calendar to add appointment, after that while creating  appointmentId , it throws an **value does not fall within the expected range** error. Can you guide the possibilities of the error. I didn't pass any value. I just tried sample as you suggest as a sample document http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/149C1734/17CF7930